# How to aggregate one column according to the other column in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, octave, transformation

I have .mat file, where are two columns "Product" and "Customer". Customer number is repeated as many times as he purchased different products. The table looks like that:

```
  Product Customer    
      114        1    
      112        2    
      112        1   
      113        4    
      115        3    
      113        2   
      111        2    
      113        3
```

And I need to make it like this:

```
    Customer 111 112 113 114 115
           1   0   1   0   1   0
           2   1   1   1   0   0
           3   0   0   1   0   1
           4   0   0   1   0   0
```

In new table have to be "Customer" column and five more columns for each product and if the customer "1" bought product "112" there should be 1 ind if he didn't buy it should be 0.
How can I do it with MATLAB? Any help would be very nice!

Comment: Your sample data does not include this but what about multiple purchases? What would the output be if customer `1` bought `112` three times?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that, if customer bought the same product three times, it would be perfect if there would be 3 not 1

Comment: `sparse(Customer, Product, 1)`?

Comment: Actually it isn't working as supposed to. I am doing it like this:  `sparse(Customer, Product, 1)`.The sparse matrix in this case is `4x115` and it has to be `4x5`. It is making columns from 1 to 115, not from 111 as supposed to.

Comment: @knedlsepp That was going to be my suggestion too! :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is a classic case for [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html).

```
>> product = [114, 112, 112, 113, 115, 113, 111, 113]';
>> customer = [1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3]';
>> [~,~,ic] = unique(product);
>> accumarray([customer, ic], 1)

ans =

     0     1     0     1     0
     1     1     1     0     0
     0     0     1     0     1
     0     0     1     0     0
```

Here we use `unique` to work out the unique product IDs, and the third output is the mapping from the `product` vector to the unique ID.

Comment: And how would you deal with multiple purchases?

Comment: @kkuilla that seems to work fine for me even when there are multiple purchases.

Comment: @Benoit_11 Yes, you are right. I should have tested it myself first. I think this is an excellent solution.

Comment: Yep, it's definitely exactly what `accumarray` is for - also note the second argument can be a vector - so if there were a third column of "number of purchases", you could put that in there.

Answer (score 1):

Say `N_of_pr` is the total number of products, `N_of_cus` is the total number of customers, and `tab` is the first two-column table you have. The resulting binary matrix is `M`

```
pr=zeros(1,N_of_pr);
cus=zeros(1,N_of_cus);

s=size(tab);

for j=1:s(1)
    pr(tab(j,1))=1;
    cus(tab(j,2))=1;
end;

[X,Y]=meshgrid(pr,cus);

M=X.*Y;
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but it isn't working, when I'm trying this code I get "Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options." I tried to do it with only two lines, but still I get this error, it couldn't be, that I have no space on my computer...

Answer (score 0):

You could either use basic MATLAB commands like `sparse`

```
table = sparse(Customer, Product, 1);
```

or something like `grpstats` from the statistics toolbox.

```
t = table(Product, Customer);
grpstats(t, {'Customer','Product'})
```

This doesn't yield exactly the table you want, but I guess you could still achieve your goal with that.

There is also a submission called [`pivottable`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30547-pivottable) on the File Exchange, that will do what you want:

```
pivottable([Customer, Product, ones(size(Product))], 1, 2, 3, @sum)
```

Comment: thank you for answering, I would like to use command `sparse`, because my real table is much more bigger than this one, it is only a part of it. So `sparse` would save same memory, but as I wrote under first answer if I am using `sparse` then it is creating `115` columns instead of `5`...

Comment: @MiglėPapuškaitė: You can't have columns starting from `111`. You would either have to renumber the product IDs from `1` to `5` using `[~, Product]=unique(Product)` or just leave it as it is. (In terms of memory it doesn't really matter, if you want to keep the `111`, you should probably just go with `sparse`.)